# Encode video file using service, change creation time of new video to match original, delete original

Tags: macos, filesystem, automation, encoding

When storing photos or videos from different cameras in the same folder the only option to keep some time-sequence is to sort by date.

I am using the service ‘encode selected video files’ to convert AVI movies (my olympus records AVIs) to MOV, saving tons of space. However, the new file keeps the name of the original file but not the creation date and I have to change it manually with ‘touch -t’ and then delete the original file. Otherwise, the file is messed up with the photos and does not keep the sequence when sorted by date.

I am sure this can be automated with ‘automator’ but don’t know anything about it. Just managed to create a service that has the resolution pre-selected so at least I skip one pop-up.

Can somebody help me to create a service that, given a selected movie file, launches the ‘encode selected video file’ and then changes the date of the new file to match the original and deletes the original? And if it is possible to do it with several files at the same time it would be great !

Thanks!
Antonio

Comment: Taking a look at it now, looks like using `touch [NEW FILE] -r [ORIGINAL FILE]` then just removing the original file is the answer.

Comment: Thanks !! After try and error and reading the man again I found out that it's  'touch -r [ORIGINAL FILE] [NEW FILE]’. Still looking for a way to automate it though ;-D

Comment: My bad :) I'm not great with Automator (I tend to use AppleScript more), but files should pass from one to the other and–using a shell script action thing–this should be possible. Gotta figure out variables and stuff tho.

Comment: Finally got it !!  Just created a service to clone timestamp and delete the original file. The service obtains the selected files (select original first and new second), does the touch command using $1 and $2 (didn’t know is the list of parameters) and then deletes $1. It works, not all-in-one, video encoding and timestamp cloning, but two easy steps. Thanks JMY1000 !!

Comment: Awesome! Add that as the answer!